# Allowing encoded characters in an MVC Get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, escaping

I have an MVC controller with the following method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Image(int image, string message)
    {
```

I want this to be a GET because it's the appropriate verb to use for the method I'm implementing.

I want to supply "Does this work?" as a parameter to the method. Obviously this is not going to work:

```
http://localhost:55197/Controller/Image/3/Does%20this%20work?
```

The question mark is considered part of the query string and is removed. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357032/question-mark-in-the-middle-of-a-url-variable) which suggests encoding the question mark to `%3F`, this makes sense to me (after all we encode our spaces). However when I call the method with this query string:

```
http://localhost:55197/Controller/Image/3/Does%20this%20work%3F
```

I get

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (?).

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc) which suggests using the `[AllowHtml]` attribute, but this can only be used on properties (and is therefore more appropriate to POST requests.

How can I pass strings like:

> Does this work?
>
> I think so...

Into this method?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code in **web.config** file :-

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: This seems very drastic, can you expand on the security implications of turning off validations on all requests!?

Comment: @Liath..Well Yes ...you have to specify the settings in web.config as shown above...there is no other option.