# How to create the routeProvider for URLs with question mark?

Tags: angularjs

Overall my URLs follow the standard http://sitename/something#/rounds/2
The "when" to `routeProvider` goes like this:

```
.when('/rounds/:param', {
   templateUrl:,
   label:,
})
```

Ok, but now I have an URL with a question mark like this: http://sitename/something#/rounds/2?add_on=2

How can I make the `routerProvider` "when" deal with this?
This do not works:

```
.when('/rounds/:param:param', {
    templateUrl:,
    label:,
})
```

How make this kind of URL works?

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357032/question-mark-in-the-middle-of-a-url-variable

Comment: this is covered in the documentation

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068511/passing-parameter-with-ngroute

Answer (score 0):

URL GET parameters (like *add_on=2*) do not affect $routeProvider url matching, so both links (with *?add_on=2* and without) will match this:

```
.when('/rounds/:param', {
  templateUrl: .....
})
```

all URL variables will be stored in $routeParams service:
  --

#/rounds/2

```
{
  "param": "2"
}
```

and   --

#/rounds/2?add_on=2

```
{
  "add_on": "2",
  "param": "2"
}
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QY8QBykgdpCUIpxQC35m