# Apache QueryString

Tags: regex, apache, query-string, querystringparameter

I currently am able to use the Apache QueryString and it works ok....as long as I don't have multiple "?"

However I recently came across one.  Something like this

```
http://path/index.shtml?dynContent=project-panel?id=A123456789
```

And I am using this currently for getting the QueryString. (This works fine if there are not multiple "?" in the string)

```
    <!--#if expr="$testQueryString = On && $QUERY_STRING = /dynContent=(.*)/" -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="$1" -->
<!--#else -->
<!--#set var="dynContent" value="default" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

Any idea how I can just target "project-panel" and not the rest?

Using Apache 2.4 and no php.

I don't have access to do the Rewrite.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple question marks in your URL. The second one should be URL-encoded, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357032/question-mark-in-the-middle-of-a-url-variable. If `id` is a second GET parameter, then it should be preceded by `&`, not `?`

Comment: ah....ok....I did replace the 2nd ? with & and modified the  $QUERY_STRING to $QUERY_STRING = /dynContent=(.*?)\&/ and that seemed to work