# Android - retrofit - Query parameters missing from Base Url

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp

I am working on an android app using Dagger2 + Retrofit + RxAndroid + OkHttp3 + New architecture components. **Min sdk = 16**.

Issue : When running the app on API 16, the Url generation is not correct. Url is missing the @QueryMap parameters I am passing via Retrofit. The same is working fine when I am testing the app on api levels 21+.

Correct url - 
on api 21+ - "http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json?q=IDR&days=10&key=apikey"

url generated on api 16/19 - "http://api.apixu.com/v1/forecast.json"

Retrofit Interface -

```
@GET("forecast.json")
fun fetchWeatherDetails(
    @QueryMap hashMap: @NotNull HashMap<String, String>
): @NotNull Observable<ApiResponse>
```

Retrofit Builder -

```
val httpClient = getOkHttpClient()
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(apiBaseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()
```

OkHttpClient -

```
val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    builder
        .cache(cache)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .followSslRedirects(true)

    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    } else {
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
    }

    builder.addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor())
        .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
    return builder.build()
```

Its been more than 2 days since I am stuck in this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Update : 
Api query Code is working fine on API 21+.

Failed on API-16 & API-19.

Comment: Your issue is weird, can't say anything but one suggestion, try to using query rather then QueryMap. May fix your issue.

Comment: Tried. With @Query - Same issue.  When passed the entire url - it was working fine. The issue I believe is simple - url being parsed on api23+ but not on api 16. I was wondering if it has anything to do with backward compatibility for api level 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious that your *URL* didn't encoded, to do so you need to insure that it's get encoded on all platforms using `@QueryMap(encoded = true)`.

If it doesn't success I'm afraid that you need to do that manually using custom **interceptor** to encode such characters like `?` which equal to `%3F`, e.g:

```
@Override
    Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request()
        def string = request.url().toString()
        string = string.replace("%26", "&")
        string = string.replace("%3D", "=")
        string = string.replace("%3F", "?")

        Request newRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(string)
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }
```

**References:**

- [Question mark in the middle of a url variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357032/question-mark-in-the-middle-of-a-url-variable)
- https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199

Comment: So why is it working in api level 23+ and not in api level 16? That is the main question. The retrofit is querying the url properly and displaying results as expected in api23+. But when I am running it on api16 -> gives error. And in the log I can see that the url which is queried is not parsed properly.

Comment: @PranavBhoraskar I believe there is a support drop 16+ i.e: annotation or some of external API's, which will be hard to fix with existence of API **29**.

Answer (score 1):

Man, read the OkHttp Requirements section: https://github.com/square/okhttp#requirements It literally mentions only 3.12.x branch supports Android 2.3+ (API level 9+) and Java 7+. It was duo to lack support for TLS 1.2 for device < API 21. If you really wanna support anything that under API 21 then update your OkHttp version to 3.12.x which will be still available til December 31, 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!! I solved the issue. 
Solution - Trick was to use Interceptor. With checks for correct SDK VERSION and interceptor, finally I got my thing running.

```
internal class HeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {    
var request = chain.request()    
val url = request.url().newBuilder()
            .addQueryParameter("key", API_KEY)
            .addQueryParameter("q", QUERY_PARAMETER)
            .addQueryParameter("days", DAYS)
            .build()
request = request.newBuilder().url(url).build()
return chain.proceed(request)
  }
}
```

OkHttpClient needed SDK_VERSION check -

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   builder.addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor())
}
```

So catch here for me was - @QueryMap(in retrofit) worked fine to build the url for SDK-21+. For SDKs<21 I used interceptor as mentioned above for building the url.

I thank you all for the help on this matter. I believe someone out there would find this helpful!!